# Allow favorite tags in Documentation

Tags: feature-request, documentation

Add a "my tags" or "favorite" tab which lists the tags I am interested in, so I don't need to "type to find a tag" every time.

[image: my tags]

Comment: Maybe also highlight them where they appear in the list too, like the questions tagged with your favorite tags.