# Do the powers that be still care about "Documentation"?

Tags: discussion, documentation

The reason for my question is a regrettable lack of reaction to (at least one) feature request.

All 4 questions about the lack of *favorites* (posted since June 2016, all with [feature-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) haven't got a **single** answer.

- [How to favorite a Documentation tag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/330086/how-to-favorite-a-documentation-tag)
- [documentation - "Mark as favorite" button really lacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334513/documentation-mark-as-favorite-button-really-lacks)
- [Add an ability to star documentation entries as favorite](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332764/add-an-ability-to-star-documentation-entries-as-favorite)
- [Allow favorite tags in Documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328465/allow-favorite-tags-in-documentation)

My beef is not with the fact that this feature is not implemented (Although, as a consumer of *Documentation*, I'd like to have it) but with the fact that no one gave **any** answer.

Comment: There's loads of feature requests that haven't received any answer from the team yet... from what they've said it didn't sound like they don't care about Documentation any more. Quite the contrary actually.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> My beef is not with the fact that this feature is not implemented (Although, as a consumer of *Documentation*, I'd like to have it) but with the fact that no one gave **any** answer.

And how is that in any way different from the multitude of non-Docs.SO feature requests that have also gone unanswered?

The Powers That Be don't respond to all feature requests. They never have. This doesn't indicate how much they care or don't care about a particular part of the site.

---

As for that particular feature request... what's the point? You're using a *web browser*. You are perfectly capable of "favoriting" a specific piece of Docs.SO yourself. Why do they need to add this to the site.

Comment: I was not aware of a *multitude of non-Docs.SO feature requests that have also gone unanswered* - admittedly didn't search for them.

Comment: @guntbert: There are [thousands on MSO](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request+-status-completed+-status-bydesign+-status-declined+-status-norepro+-status-deferred+-status-planned+-status-review+-status-reproduced), and [more than ten thousand more on MSE](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request+-status-completed+-status-bydesign+-status-declined+-status-norepro+-status-deferred+-status-planned+-status-review+-status-reproduced). (Admittedly, some of those have been *touched* by an employee at some point in the past… but without any official resolution.)